# EL is not working for getting a Java Bean

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, el

Basically the trouble is that I cannot get the property of a java bean in a jsp page. I'm using example from book Java EE7 Recipes. I have next statements in the body of a JSP page:

```
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="dateBean" scope="application" class="business.DateBean" />
    <h2>The current date is: ${dateBean.currentDate}</h2>
</body>
```

The error NetBeans is ponting to is in part:

```
${dateBean.currentDate}
```

The Java Bean Class I'm ussing is the following:

```
package business;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateBean implements java.io.Serializable {

private Date currentDate = new Date();

public Date getCurrentDate() {
    return currentDate;
}

public void setCurrentDate(Date currentDate) {
    this.currentDate = currentDate;
}

}//DateBean
```

Whenever I try to run the JSP, the error I get is the following:

```
PWC6038: "${dateBean.currentDate}" contains invalid expression(s): 
javax.el.ELException: Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type: 
org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
```

Doing some reserach I have found that the tag below may be missing, so I have added (in JSP page)  but still not working.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Does anybody know what could be wrong? Thank you a lot!!!

The complete jsp file looks as following:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
</head>

<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="dateBean" scope="application" class="business.DateBean" />
    <h2>The current date is: ${dateBean.currentDate}</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: may we see your whole jsp file?

Comment: what are the jar file or dependencies you have in lib folder or CLASSPATH?

Comment: Please find below the jar files I have in lib folder (C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib): `javafx.jar
dt.jar
javafx-mx.jar
jconsole.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
sa-jdi.jar
tools.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With scope="application", you would need to do this:

```
${applicationScope.dataBean.currentDate}.
```

You probably don't want that date to be set as application scope though, so remove scope="application" from the  tag like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="dateBean" class="business.DateBean" />
```

Also you need to import your class into your JSP, so place this at the top:

```
<%@ page import="business.DateBean" %>
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried both suggestions but doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it could be a configuration trouble in NetBeans 8.0. Let's wait for more suggestions.

Comment: Finally I run program with directions, and it work fine though    NetBeans mark an error. After compiling error disappear and just mark a syntaxis error. (kind of queer but finally work) Thanks